# How to pass arguments in cmd to FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass arguments through the command line to monitor folders with How to pass arguments in cmd to FileSystemWatcher but I'm not getting it.

What I want is to be able to pass the command directly into the CMD, for example:

```
monitor.exe C/:path/monitor
```

code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

             Console.WriteLine("Path: ");
             string Path = Console.ReadLine();
         
            using var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(Path);
```

can you help me?

Comment: Careful with the tagging. This is clearly not C++ code, so attracting the attention of C++ programmers is unlikely to help, and if the question is weak their attentions will likely only provide extra down and close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

put your path in quotes if it contains spaces. ("c:/some path/path")
otherwise this is fine

monitor.exe C/:path/monitor

then in C#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      var path =  args[0];  
      Console.WriteLine($"Path: {path}");
         
      using var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
      {
           //do logic here with path
      }
}
```

obviously add some error checking and what to ensure the path is present, but this should get you started. Also with more than one path the args[0] will need to change, but this again should get you started.